# I have a bug in my calculator code and I don't now how to fix it

Tags: c++, math, calculator

When we insert the letter into the console, it starts repeating itself in lines 19 and 42. When I normally write an invoice it works for me.

Please help how to fix this.

[image: Picture]

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float num1, num2;
    char operator1;

    bool repeat = true;

    while (repeat)
    {

        char odgovor; //odgovor da ali ne v katerega bom spravil v bool(true / false)
        cout << "do you want to continue d(yes) or n(no) " << endl;
        cin >> odgovor;
        repeat = odgovor == 'd';

        cout << "enter the calculation" << endl;

        cin >> num1 >> operator1 >> num2; //vnos dveh števil in operatorja
        switch (operator1)
        {

        case'-':cout << num1 << " " << operator1 << " " << num2 << " = " << num1 - num2 << endl; break;
        case'+':cout << num1 << " " << operator1 << " " << num2 << " = " << num1 + num2 << endl; break;
        case'/':cout << num1 << " " << operator1 << " " << num2 << " = " << num1 / num2 << endl; break;
        case'*':cout << num1 << " " << operator1 << " " << num2 << " = " << num1 * num2 << endl; break;
        case'%':
            bool isNum1Int, isNum2Int;
            isNum1Int = ((int)num1 == num1);
            isNum2Int = ((int)num2 == num2);

            if (isNum1Int && isNum2Int)
            {
                cout << (int)num1 << " " << operator1 << " " << (int)num2 << " = " << (int)num1 %(int)num2 << endl; break;
            }
            else {
                cout << "the number must be an integer" << endl; break;
            }

        default:cout << "not valid" << endl;  break;

        }

    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please choose a title for your post that will help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

> When we insert the letter into the console, it starts repeating itself in lines 19 and 42.

This line is the culprit:

```cpp
cin >> num1 >> operator1 >> num2;
```

Here, `std::cin` will first try to read an integer from the console. If you properly input an integer, nothing will happen and everything will go as intended.

However, when you pass only a character to the console, `std::cin` *fails* since it is unable to find an *integer* in your input. After `std::cin` has failed, it will not try to block execution for taking any more input, and further, you have nothing in your code that breaks out of the `while` loop so it will keep iterating indefinitely, which is what you are facing.

To fix this, you could do a check to see if `std::cin` has failed and break the loop accordingly when needed:

```cpp
// ...

cin >> num1 >> operator1 >> num2;
if (cin.fail())
    break; // Break out of the loop in case of failure

// ...
```

Comment: Alternatively: `if (!(cin >> num1 >> operator1 >> num2))  break;`